# What does "go on with" mean?

Tags: sentence-construction

> I am going to strip down certain general ideas [...] and so preapare a
> nucleus of useful knowledge for those who have to **go on with** this
> business of making a world peace.
>
> The new world order by H.G. Wells

Does it mean "continue with"?

Or does it mean something like "go with" (choosing)?

If none of the above, then what is meant?

Answer (score 1):

"Go on" is a phrasal verb. [M-W's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20on) (similar to your suggestion) is:

> a: to continue on or as if on a journey
> life *goes on*
> *went on* to greater things
>
> b: to keep on : CONTINUE
> *went on* smoking
>
> c: PROCEED
> *went on* to win the election

It is often followed by the preposition "with".

"To go with" (meaning "to choose") is a different verb, doesn't usually involve "on", and doesn't seem to make sense here.